# How do i wrap this wavy border around the hero? html/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Essentially this is what I need where the hero image is being wrapped by the wavy border (this is from a graphic):

[image]

- I tried going into Photoshop to fill in the empty space in the PNG file to be white, but it was causing jitters on the wave itself,
- I attempted clip paths but the problem is it gets ruined depending on the content being entered in the description,
- I tried linear/radial gradients to attach as before/after elements to the wave but I didn't get it to work.

(no frameworks)

My Codepen: https://codepen.io/trashboat25/pen/ZEqXWyx?editors=1100

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
  font: inherit;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1400px;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.hero3 {
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 438px;
  padding,
  100px 0 197px 0;
}

.hero3__content {
  max-width: 631px;
  color: white;
}

.hero3__heading {
  margin-bottom,
  12px;
}

`your text` .hero3__desc {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 0.45px;
}

.hero-3__wave {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 4;
}

.hero-3__wave--desktop {
  width: 100%;
}
```